# Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. creationOptions at apnsBroker.Start()

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification

I created an console app with .NET 4.0 like this:

```
static void Test2(string deviceToken, string message)
{
    try
    {

        //Get Certificate
        var appleCert = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Certificates_moi.p12");

        // Configuration (NOTE: .pfx can also be used here)
        var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, appleCert, "vnpt1234");

        // Create a new broker
        var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);

        // Wire up events
        apnsBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) =>
        {

            aggregateEx.Handle(ex =>
            {

                // See what kind of exception it was to further diagnose
                if (ex is ApnsNotificationException)
                {
                    var notificationException = (ApnsNotificationException)ex;

                    // Deal with the failed notification
                    var apnsNotification = notificationException.Notification;
                    var statusCode = notificationException.ErrorStatusCode;
                    string desc = "Apple Notification Failed: ID={apnsNotification.Identifier}, Code={statusCode}";
                    Console.WriteLine(desc);
                    //lblStatus.Text = desc;
                }
                else
                {
                    string desc = "Apple Notification Failed for some unknown reason : {ex.InnerException}";
                    // Inner exception might hold more useful information like an ApnsConnectionException           
                    Console.WriteLine(desc);
                    //lblStatus.Text = desc;
                }

                // Mark it as handled
                return true;
            });
        };

        apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) =>
        {
            //lblStatus.Text = "Apple Notification Sent successfully!";
            Console.WriteLine("Apple Notification Sent successfully!");
        };

        var fbs = new FeedbackService(config);
        fbs.FeedbackReceived += (string devicToken, DateTime timestamp) =>
        {
            // Remove the deviceToken from your database
            // timestamp is the time the token was reported as expired
        };

        // Start Proccess 
        apnsBroker.Start();

        if (deviceToken != "")
        {
            apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
            {
                DeviceToken = deviceToken,
                Payload = JObject.Parse(("{\"aps\":{\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"oven.caf\",\"alert\":\"" + (message + "\"}}")))
            });
        }

        apnsBroker.Stop();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

There is an error at apnsBroker.Start();
-       $exception  {"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: creationOptions"} System.Exception {System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException}
Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue. Move to another machine running .NET 4.5 and it worked.